# Python: (request module) Does my program request twice?

Tags: python

I have a question about python and variables.

```
spell1Id_match1 = match_spell1[my_summoner_id]
request_spell1name = requests.get('https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/summoner-spell/{0}?api_key=REMOVED'.format(spell1Id_match1)).json()
spell1Name_match1 = (request_spell1name['name'])
```

If each time I do something like `spell1Name_match1 = (request_spell1name['name'])`, will I use the `request.get` function? Or will python store it the first time and then that's that? The API I'm using is limited in the amount of requests I'm allowed to make.

I wrote this as a simple logic test:

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = x + y
print(z)
y = 3
x = 6
print(z)
```

The output is:

```
2
2
```

So, python does not update the `z`?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request is sent once when you call `requests.get()`, and then you have the result in a dict-like object (using `.json()`) that you are reading from, multiple times.

Conceptually, what happens when you get the JSON is equivalent to this:

```
  # response = request.get(...).json()
>>> response = {'name': 'bakkal'}   # You have a dict
>>> response['name']                # You read from the dict saved in memory (no HTTP)
'bakkal'
```

So no HTTP call is made after the first one that got us the JSON data

<sub>And in your second example, no Python does not automatically recalculate the value of `z`, you'd have to run `z = x + y` again for that to happen (at least that won't happen for plain integers)</sub>

Comment: If I send the Json to a function (def find_summoner_name) to find the values for the a key, lets call the key "SummonerName". find_summoner_name requires a request to a static library. Each time I call the find_summoner_name function, will I make a request? I understand your first answer where the HTTP request converts it to a dict-like object, but if I call the function that has the request.get module, the function will always make the request? Seeing as functions don't store variables unless you use `return`? Is that all right?

Comment: If you call a function that calls `request.get()` everytime it is called, then `request.get()` will be called and result in a HTTP request being sent yes. So if possible you should e.g. make the HTTP request one time, store it then read it. I see you have to send the summoner_id each time maybe you don't have a choice but to make many HTTP requests for each summoner_id (unless e.g. the HTTP API can return a list of several name/summoner_id in one or a few calls)